# How to replace the last string of an url by another string

Tags: python, url

I have a data set that contains the url to web pages.
I have something like this :

- https://abc.eu/login or https://abc.eu/ or  https://abc.eu/ar35gjdb4

I am trying to replace all the urls by what's after the last "/" so I'm simply using

```
df["url"].str.split("/").str[-1]
```

But I'd like for the urls that have a long string composed of both letters and numbers (like the third link) to be replaced by "valid" and those that have nothing at the end after the last "/" to be replaced by "home_page", how do I achieve that?

I'd like to have something like this:

- login
- home_page
- valid

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code to achieve the above requirement:

```
urls = ["https://abc.eu/login", "https://abc.eu/", "https://abc.eu/ar35gjdb4"]

for url in urls:
    s = url.rsplit('/', 1)
    if s[1] == 'login':
        print(os.path.join(s[0], 'login'))
    elif s[1] == '': 
        print(os.path.join(s[0], 'home_page'))
    elif re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$', s[1]):
        print(os.path.join(s[0], 'valid'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse url with
[this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html). Then you can replace.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).